# How to enable MapKit floor level?

Tags: swift, mapkit

I am trying to show floor level into my apple app. I know in apple map there are some selected place like airport or shopping mall where this floor level can be seen. I need to achieve exactly that. Just need to show the floor level where this is available. As you can see in the picture, in the right hand side of the image there are 5F,4F,3F,2F etc. I have searched the net but left with no clue yet.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to use MKOverlay. You would add each floor as an overlay to your MKMapView and show whatever floor the user selects, hide the others.

Here is a sample for making an overlay:

```
import MapKit

class MapOverlay: NSObject, MKOverlay {
  var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
  var boundingMapRect: MKMapRect

  override init() {
    let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 75.3307, longitude: -152.1929) // change these for the position of your overlay
    let mapSize = MKMapSize(width: 240000000, height: 200000000) // change these numbers for the width and height of your image
    boundingMapRect = MKMapRect(origin: MKMapPoint(location), size: mapSize)
    coordinate = location
    super.init()
  }
}

class MapOverlayRenderer: MKOverlayRenderer {
  let overlayImage: UIImage
  init(overlay: MKOverlay, image: UIImage) {
    self.overlayImage = image
    super.init(overlay: overlay)
  }

  override func draw(_ mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, in context: CGContext) {
    guard let imageReference = overlayImage.cgImage else { return }

    let rect = self.rect(for: overlay.boundingMapRect)
    context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
    context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: -rect.size.height)
    context.draw(imageReference, in: rect)
  }
}
```

Then add it to your map:

```
let mapOverlay = MapOverlay()
mapView.addOverlay(mapOverlay)
```

And don't forget the delegate:

```
mapView.delegate = self

extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
  func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    return MapOverlayRenderer(overlay: overlay, image: UIImage(named: "overlayImage")!)
  }
}
```